# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,55) (42,)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, python-2.7

[To Download Dataset click link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q4iJOHgRfuZDmQY-Iv2-M4t3A3ECpiTn/view?usp=sharing)

I am trying to find out disease type based on the symptoms, by using a machine learning model. All are going well but when I trying to predict the disease type based on given symptoms it gives me "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,55) (42,) "  that error. to solve this i have seen many of the similar post but not able to solve it.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

import re
import string
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
from nlppreprocess import NLP

import math
import string
punct = string.punctuation
import spacy
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
#nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
from spacy.lang.en.stop_words import STOP_WORDS

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix,accuracy_score, classification_report, roc_curve, auc

from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
gnb = GaussianNB()
```

[input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppEHm.png)

```
w = pd.read_csv("symptom_disease.csv")

w = w.fillna(int(0))

X = w.drop(["Disease"],axis=1)

m = w["Disease"]

data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=["disease"])

gnb=gnb.fit(X,np.ravel(y))
```

[X.head()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKaHs.png)

```
X.head()

output:

Passing much less urine Bleeding from any body part Feeling extremely lethargic/weak    Excessive sleepiness/restlessness   Altered mental status   Seizure/fits    Breathlessness  Blood in sputum Chest pain  Sound/noise in breathing    ... diarrhoea   sweats and chills   difficulty breathing    sweating and shivering  rapid heartbeat sweating    shivering   loss of appetite    coughing up blood   vomiting
0   1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
1   0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
2   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
3   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
4   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0







import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
t = ['Passing much less urine','Bleeding from any body part','Feeling extremely lethargic/weak','Excessive sleepiness/restlessness','Altered mental status','Seizure/fits','Breathlessness','Blood in sputum','Chest pain','Sound/noise in breathing','Drooling of saliva','Difficulty in opening mouth','Eye irritation','Runny nose','Stuffy nose','watery eyes','Sneezing','itchy nose','itchy throat','fever','headache','intense pain','fatigue','dry cough','bloody stools','loose stools','nausea','shortness of breath','tight chest','cough','short of breath','muscle pains','diarrhoea','sweats and chills','difficulty breathing','sweating and shivering','rapid heartbeat','sweating','shivering','loss of appetite','coughing up blood','vomiting','Weakness','Stomach pain','constipation','Cough','Chills','Abdominal pain','Yellow skin color','skin color yellow','Dark-colored urine','clay-colored stool','yellow color urine','weight loss','itchy skin']
#t = ['Passing much less urine', 'Bleeding from any body part', 'Feeling extremely lethargic/weak', 'Excessive sleepiness/restlessness', 'Altered mental status', 'Seizure/fits', 'Breathlessness', 'Blood in sputum', 'Chest pain', 'Sound/noise in breathing', 'Drooling of saliva', 'Difficulty in opening mouth']
docs = nlp.pipe(t)

l1= []
for doc in docs:
    clean_doc = " ".join([tok.lemma_.lower() for tok in doc if not tok.is_stop and not tok.is_punct])
    l1.append(clean_doc)







l2=[]
for i in range(0,len(l1)):
    l2.append(0)
print(l2)


import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

psymptoms = ["Blood in sputum","Chest pain","Sound/noise in breathing","Breathlessness"]
docs = nlp.pipe(psymptoms)

sym= []
for doc in docs:
    clean_doc = " ".join([tok.lemma_.lower() for tok in doc if not tok.is_stop and not tok.is_punct])
    sym.append(clean_doc)


for k in range(0,len(l1)):
    for z in sym:
        #print(z)
        if(z==l1[k]):
            l2[k]=1

inputtest = [l2]
predict = gnb.predict(inputtest)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-d99236746b75> in <module>
      1 #print(inputtest)
----> 2 predict = gnb.predict(inputtest)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py in predict(self, X)
     76         check_is_fitted(self)
     77         X = self._check_X(X)
---> 78         jll = self._joint_log_likelihood(X)
     79         return self.classes_[np.argmax(jll, axis=1)]
     80 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py in _joint_log_likelihood(self, X)
    454             jointi = np.log(self.class_prior_[i])
    455             n_ij = - 0.5 * np.sum(np.log(2. * np.pi * self.sigma_[i, :]))
--> 456             n_ij -= 0.5 * np.sum(((X - self.theta_[i, :]) ** 2) /
    457                                  (self.sigma_[i, :]), 1)
    458             joint_log_likelihood.append(jointi + n_ij)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,55) (42,)
```

[Error msg picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/golhU.png)

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot) in question (not comment).

Comment: @furas, Now I added the dataset also, code and error msg already added thank you for your suggestion. Help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, finally I solved it.
Actually, there is a dimensional problem.
Problems come because I was given an input data dimension of the model is X=(10 rows × 42 columns) and y = (10 rows × 1 column).
and when use the model for prediction then I was given a test data dimension of = (1 rows × 55 columns). That's the problem of dimension. Now I changed my input data shape of X = (10 rows × 55 columns). So now it works fine and predicted well.